# C++ OpenGL glCreateProgram returns 0 on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL using C++ and Visual Studio, and when I run my program it prompts the display window quickly and then crashes leading me to a break point that says "Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in OpenGL.exe: 0xC000000005: Access violation.".

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <sdl2/SDL.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>

GLuint crearShader (const std :: string & texto, GLenum tipo);
std :: string cargarShader (const std :: string & nombreArchivo);
void comprobarErrorShader (GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool esPrograma, const std :: string & mensaje);

void display () 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    SDL_Window * ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext contexto = SDL_GL_CreateContext(ventana);
    GLenum estado = glewInit();

    if (estado != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        std :: cerr << "Fallo al inicializar Glew." << std :: endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GLuint programa = glCreateProgram(); // <-- Problem goes here.
    const unsigned int NUM_SHADERS = 2;
    GLuint shaders[ NUM_SHADERS ];
    shaders[0] = crearShader(cargarShader("./shaderBasico.vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    shaders[1] = crearShader(cargarShader("./shaderBasico.fs"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++) 
    {
        glAttachShader(programa, shaders[ i ]);
    }

    glLinkProgram(programa);
    comprobarErrorShader(programa, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "Error: Fallo al vincular el programa: ");

    glValidateProgram(programa);
    comprobarErrorShader(programa, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, true, "Error: El programa es invalido: ");

    SDL_Event evento;

    do 
    {
        glClearColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(programa);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(ventana);
        SDL_PollEvent(&evento);
    }
    while (evento.type != SDL_QUIT) ;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++) 
    {
        glDetachShader(programa, shaders[ i ]);
        glDeleteShader(shaders[ i ]);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(programa);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexto);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(ventana);
    SDL_Quit();
}

GLuint crearShader (const std :: string & texto, GLenum tipo) 
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(tipo);

    if (shader == 0) 
    {
        std :: cerr << "Error al crear shader." << std :: endl;
    }

    const GLchar * shaderSourceStrings[1] = {texto.c_str()};
    GLint shaderSourceStringLengths[1] = {texto.length()};
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, shaderSourceStrings, shaderSourceStringLengths);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    comprobarErrorShader(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, true, "Error: Fallo al vincular el programa: ");

    return shader;
}

std :: string cargarShader (const std :: string & nombreArchivo) 
{
    std :: ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str());

    std :: string salida;
    std :: string linea;

    if (archivo.is_open()) 
    {
        while (archivo.good()) 
        {
            getline(archivo, linea);
            salida.append(linea + "\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std :: cerr << "Error, no se pudo cargar un shader." << std :: endl;
    }

    return salida;
}

void comprobarErrorShader (GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool esPrograma, const std :: string & mensaje) 
{
    GLint exito = 0;
    GLchar error[1024] = { 0 };

    if (esPrograma) 
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, flag, &exito);
    }
    else
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, flag, &exito);
    }

    if (exito == GL_FALSE) 
    {
        if (esPrograma) 
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof error, NULL, error);
        }
        else
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, sizeof error, NULL, error);
        }

        std :: cerr << mensaje << ": '" << error << "'" << std :: endl;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I initialized glew before creating the program and still giving me errors, any ideas?

Comment: Is `glCreateProgram()` NULL?  What does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` return?  Are you doing something unusual like running in a VM or over Remote Desktop?  Anything change if you remove all the `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` calls?

Comment: Hello, glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns 1.4.0 - Build 8.14.10.2364, I tried by comenting all the SDL_GL_SetAttribute and still giving me the exception, by the way I cannot determinate the value that glCreateProgram returns because of the crash, and I'm not running in a remote desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns ***1.4.0*** - Build 8.14.10.2364

Well there you go, `glCreateProgram()` wasn't core in OpenGL 1.4.

GLEW most likely set `glCreateProgram()` to NULL.

[Check](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) if your GL implementation supports [`ARB_vertex_shader`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_shader.txt), [`ARB_fragment_shader`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/fragment_shader.txt), and [`ARB_shader_objects`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_objects.txt) and use those ARB functions instead.

If those extensions *aren't* supported then you're SOL on the shader front unless you want to use a software rasterizer like [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/).

Comment: You're right mate, my videocard wont allow me to upgrade my OpenGL version, so it doesn't support glCreateProgram, but it does for ARB_vertex_shader and ARB_fragment_shader (I checked out), so I believe it is my way to go, thank's for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. I was running visual studio over an rdp connection on my macbook. When I ran it on my PC that was hosting the connection it worked fine.